# width 100% footer issue - HTML CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a big problem. Im designing a Landing Page but I have a problem with the footer element!

I set its width on 100% but when i preview it in the browser it's not 100% but it left a few pixels' border on the left, on the right and on the bottom.

This is footer's CSS:

```
footer {
width: 100%;
background: white;
height: 100px;
margin-top: 100px;

}
```

anything changes also if I add somethings like: left: 0px; bottom: 0px; or right:0px;

How can I do?

this is an image if I didnt explain the problem very well.

http://tinypic.com/r/zsoh8m/6

Comment: Can I see the entire CSS file?

Comment: Please give your HTML code or just create a fiddle on http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you did not reset the `padding` and `margin` values on the `body` tag. Browser use a standard set of CSS rules there, which oftentimes includes some paddings and margins there.

Add this to your CSS:

```
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems the parent element (maybe `<body>` or any `<div>`) has a fixed width or some margin and/or padding.

`width:100%;` takes all available space provided by the parent element. If the parent has a width of 700px for example, so your footer will also have this with.

Answer (score 1):

it looks like that's rather the margin/padding of your body element and not the one of the footer itself. try adding the following to your body's CSS tag:

```
body
{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```

also add those 2 properties to your footer css tag, just to make sure it doesnt inherit anything from another element.

Answer (score 0):

This looks a mergin / padding problem. you can reset the padding of the body and the margin of the footer so that it covers the 100% width

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

footer {
    margin: 0px;
}
```